# Should my reaction be any different when title=post content?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, low-quality-posts, title

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62493129/10713244). Here, the post content is letter-for-letter identical to the title (except one space), which is not even that long - 118 characters. Normally, I'd just flag a post with such content (no-effort question, that's another issue), maybe leave a comment, and go along. Should my actions be any different here, where even less effort went into asking, not even to try title the question properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your reaction shouldn't be any different: you should handle questions like this the same way that you would handle any other low-quality question that you thought needed to be closed.

You are, of course, correct in noting that the body being an exact match to the title is a very good heuristic for a low-quality question. When you see something like that, you should definitely be thinking to yourself, "Hmm…this *probably* doesn't meet our quality standards." You should then perform the normal and customary due diligence—you know, reading the post. And then you should vote and/or flag accordingly.

I've handled this case now. As should be evident from how I handled it, the correct course of action would be to raise a flag (or vote, depending your privilege level) indicating that the question should be closed for want of clarity.

The only cases where your reaction should be any different are when the post is spam (the definition of that should be obvious) or rude/abusive (rude == so thoroughly rude that it cannot be salvaged by an edit; abusive == [gibberish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234032/why-dont-we-treat-rubbish-the-same-as-spam/234035#234035)). For these, you should raise the corresponding flag.

Answer (score 5):

No, you handle all content the same. You use your judgement to look for value, pearls, usefulness. A question body that repeats its title is a tad low effort and in the same category if the body had said "see title" or "title says it all" or variations on that theme.

If you feel the question has value you can try an edit to salvage it, at least to prevent that the next visitor frowns on that question the same way you did. If salvage operation isn't viable, apply any/all of the available moderation options: Vote down, close, delete.

Because a moderator took a different approach in handling the specific example question, let's offer an alternative.

First lets remind ourselves that  *How to ...* questions are not, despite popular belief, off-topic/low quality by default. However, most instances of these type of questions are extremely useless specially when plugging the part after the *How to ...* in Bing returns thousand hits. We don't need Stack Overflow to be 1001 in that list. And if they don't generate 1000 hits then those questions run the risk of being (too) broad, which is handled by closing as Needs more focus.

After all this, you still might have found a pearl.

Looking at the question you linked (and I admit I looked at its answer as well) that looks like a useful question because official documentation at best and hopefully describes what you can do with a product/tool/API, not what you can't. The OP did include in which context they are looking to solve that programming task.

In this case a title edit makes that question better, specially if you make the title shorter. The title should be the invitation to click on the question. Don't disappoint a visitor by not offering anything extra.

As the current answer proves, the specific question is fine. In the future, when the tool/library evolves a new answer might pop-up that explains how you can achieve what is asked in version 3.11.a and let's hope that OP add some small sample code to show how it is done.

Comment: It doesn't happen that often: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1254207/questions-that-almost-have-an-identical-title-and-body

Comment: Isn't that just because all of such posts are usually deleted pretty quickly?